# Swift NSToolbarItem label custom font

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I've made an `NSToolbar` inside `NSWindow` from storyboard and sub-classed both of them. I need to set custom font for  `NSToolbarItem` label programmatically and i have searched a lot but no luck. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the NSToolbarDelegate in the AppDelegate of the application and add your own classes for that: [link](http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nstoolbar-sample-code/)